# How do I make an existing .chm file searchable?

Tags: search, chm, help-files, sumatra-pdf

I have downloaded a .chm file that is a basic python help file. When I open it using Sumatra, it does not have the search bar that has always been there for other documents. Is there anything I can do to enable help file search for this file in Sumatra? Or is there a better app for viewing .chm files that would do this automatically?

Comment: Do you use Windows 7 / 10 as your operating system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching eg. CHM's is only possible if you switch ChmUI to UseFixedPageUI.

Go to Settings > Advanced Options and set the following option to true.  If true, the UI used for PDF documents will be used for CHM documents as well.

```
ChmUI [
    UseFixedPageUI = true
]
```

If you don't want to change this option you can switch quickly from Sumatra PDF to Microsoft HTMLHelp Viewer (File > Open in Microsoft HTML Help) for using the CHM's build in search tab (in German "Suchen") on Windows.

You'll find some further information about [Full Text Search Help Viewer](http://www.help-info.de/en/Help_Info_HTMLHelp/hh_fts.htm) when using Microsoft's Help Viewer.

[image]

Comment: Vote as well as answer acceptance for two distinct solutions, both useful to me.